# mavericks macports installed outdated

Tags: operating-system, macports

After I upgrade to OS X Mavericks, all the installed ports become outdated. I can't use my gcc any more, please help.

```
The following installed ports are outdated:
bzip2                          1.0.6_0 < 1.0.6_0  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
cctools                        839_2 < 839_2  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
cctools-headers                839_0 < 839_0  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
cloog                          0.18.0_0 < 0.18.0_0  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
curl                           7.33.0_0 < 7.33.0_0  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
curl-ca-bundle                 7.33.0_0 < 7.33.0_0  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
cyrus-sasl2                    2.1.25_4 < 2.1.25_4  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
db46                           4.6.21_8 < 4.6.21_8  (platform darwin 12 != darwin 13)  
...
...
```

Answer (score 4):

The MacPorts crew expect to have a binary installer for Mavericks in the next few days. Updates won't work because the location of the Tcl framework has changed, breaking common port commands. However, just because a port is outdated doesn't mean it can't be used.

If you can't wait, there are instructions [here](http://www.ghostwheel.com/merlin/Personal/notes/2013/10/05/macports-on-mavericks/) on how to build from source, once you've upgraded Xcode, command line utilities, etc. It reflects the new location of the Tcl framework.

Comment: still have problems with the latest version of macports. Followed all steps of [macportsMigration](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration), but macports still doesn't find tcl: 'tclIndex": no such file or directory', although '/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/' exits

Comment: well as I said I followed all the steps of the macportMigration guide and it still isn't working with the latest version of macports (binary installer)

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107504/cant-update-macports-after-upgrading-to-mavericks

Comment: it turned out I had too many developer preview versions of Xcode around which screwed my $DEVELEOPER_DIR. `xcode-select --reset` made everything working again

Comment: Loaded the Mavericks pkg on Nov. 18, 2013, and this version has resolved my issues for Macports. http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html         OS X 10.9 Mavericks:
MacPorts-2.2.1-10.9-Mavericks.pkg

Answer (score 3):

That's not a bug, but intended behavior. See https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration for a guide on what to do after an OS upgrade. Note that you'll currently have to build MacPorts from source on Mavericks (but a binary installer will be available soon).

Most of your installed ports should continue to work, though, so your GCC should not be broken by this unless you start upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

If you've just upgraded your OS don't forget to:

1. Update Xcode and
2. Open it to agree to the licensing terms.