# Can't update Macports (with Mac OS X Mavericks)

Tags: macos, upgrade, macports, osx-mavericks

After upgrading Mac OS X to newest version Mavericks, I attempted to selfupdate my Macports, but it failed:

```
$ sudo port -v selfupdate
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 69 bytes  210.00 bytes/sec
total size is 4925440  speedup is 46908.95
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 76 bytes  74.67 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.57
MacPorts base version 2.2.0 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.2.1 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 70 bytes  70.67 bytes/sec
total size is 57702400  speedup is 544362.26
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 77 bytes  75.33 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.53
receiving file list ... rsync: change_dir "tarballs/PortIndex_darwin_13_i386" (in release) failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 4 bytes  received 9 bytes  26.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(1400) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/PortIndex_darwin_13_i386/PortIndex /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 23
--->  MacPorts base is outdated, installing new version 2.2.1
Installing new MacPorts release in /opt/local as root:admin; permissions 0755; Tcl-Package in /Library/Tcl

checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking MacPorts version... 2.2.1
checking for sw_vers... /usr/bin/sw_vers
checking for defaults... /usr/bin/defaults
checking for xcode-select... /usr/bin/xcode-select
checking Mac OS X version... 10.9
checking Xcode location... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
checking Xcode version... 5.0.1
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
<snip>
checking CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h presence... yes
checking for CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h... yes
checking for readline in -lreadline... yes
checking whether rl_username_completion_function is declared... no
checking whether rl_filename_completion_function is declared... yes
checking whether rl_completion_matches is declared... yes
checking whether username_completion_function is declared... yes
checking whether filename_completion_function is declared... yes
checking whether completion_matches is declared... yes
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions
Command failed: cd /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base && CC=/usr/bin/cc OBJC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make SELFUPDATING=1 && make install SELFUPDATING=1
Exit code: 1
Error: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
$
```

If I just try to upgrade a particular port, it failed too:

```
$ sudo port upgrade emacsapp
Password:
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider updating them by running 'port selfupdate'.
Error: emacsapp is not installed
$ sudo port search emacs
Password:
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider updating them by running 'port selfupdate'.
$ sudo port upgrade emacs-app
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider updating them by running 'port selfupdate'.
--->  Fetching archive for gperf
--->  Attempting to fetch gperf-3.0.4_2.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/gperf
--->  Attempting to fetch gperf-3.0.4_2.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/gperf
--->  Attempting to fetch gperf-3.0.4_2.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/gperf
--->  Fetching distfiles for gperf
--->  Attempting to fetch gperf-3.0.4.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/gperf
--->  Verifying checksums for gperf
--->  Extracting gperf
Error: org.macports.extract for port gperf returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port gperf for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gperf/gperf/main.log
Error: Problem while installing gperf
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
$
```

Any idea

- if this is caused by incompatibility between OS X Mavericks and Macports?
- how to fix it?

Edit:

I tried a different computer upgrading it from 10.8.5 to 10.9, and then try to do selfupdate for macports, it did not work again but gave a different error:

```
$ sudo port -v selfupdate
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done
base.tar

sent 13396 bytes  received 10355 bytes  15834.00 bytes/sec
total size is 4925440  speedup is 207.38
receiving file list ... done
base.tar.rmd160

sent 64 bytes  received 635 bytes  1398.00 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 0.73
MacPorts base version 2.2.1 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.2.1 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from file:///opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
Command failed: /usr/bin/svn update --non-interactive /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports
Exit code: 1
Error: Synchronization of the local ports tree failed doing an svn update
Error: Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed
```

Comment: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Install the "Command Line Tools" first:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

(Explicitly agreeing to the license is sometimes necessary via "sudo xcodebuild -license")

Then upgrade the ports:

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
```

Comment: It may also be worth noting that you should probably agree to the terms and conditions by doing: sudo xcodebuild -license .

Run through the steps and type in 'agree' and hit enter.

Comment: If you don't do this, when you run selfupdate some of the ports will fail.

Comment: For me at least, the license agreement pops up without needing to ask for it.

Comment: `xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools` ... that's it, is it supposed to do more than that?  port self update still fails...

Comment: ok, so apparently the xcode-select command is starting a GUI process... since I was connected via ssh I saw nothing.

Comment: make sure you run the command "sudo xocdebuild -license", scroll all the way to the bottom with space, and type agree.

Comment: As of April 26, 2014.  These commands no longer work.  One should perhaps download "Command Line Tools for OS X Mavericks" from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action# and install it.

Answer (score 37):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534032/mavericks-macports-installed-outdated/19554638#19554638) a similar question. The location of the Tcl framework has changed, breaking the existing MacPorts infrastructure. The 2.2.1 installer for Mavericks has since become available [here](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/). Make a list of your installed ports, and consider deleting `/opt/local` prior to installing. You will likely need to 'update' everything anyway.

Comment: Installed 2.2.1, and everything started working again. Didn't have to remove anything. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Same here. This is the correct answer. Yes, a lot of people don't install the command line tools, but that is obviously not the problem here, as the first trace provided shows.

Comment: This is indeed correct, lucky I found this answer shortly after other misleading ones elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: macosx doesn't come with tcl preinstalled, does it?

Answer (score 3):

There might be a chance that you haven't agreed with the XCode license.
If xcode-install doesn't help, you can run the belowing command to agree with Xcode license.

`sudo xcodebuild -license`

Answer (score 2):

there is an actual bug with

> gperf @3.0.4: error: expected parameter declarator

thankfully this issue has its own ticket at MacPorts [ticket 40918](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/40918)

if anything you could read all the issues in Mavericks at http://trac.macports.org/wiki/MavericksProblems

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I am assuming that you had Xcode command line utils installed previously. Just launch XCODE and let it finish configuration. Now rerun port command and it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I got an error with selfupdate, and resolved it by doing a fresh installation of MacPorts from http://www.macports.org/install.php. Now I can run the selfupdate command without error and install other ports.

The error I were seeing was below, it seems the same problem as Yo Sophia has pointed out:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
Password:
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.2.1 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
--->  MacPorts base is outdated, installing new version 2.2.1
Installing new MacPorts release in /opt/local as root:admin; permissions 0755; Tcl-Package in /Library/Tcl

Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I mainly wanted to comment on @Brett's answer above (sorry, SO n00b still, not allowed) and share my experience upgrading... not really a new answer, but hopefully some useful info.

I downloaded and installed the Mavericks MacPorts installer as described above, (but without removing /opt, as suggested by @King Julian did `self update` which was fine, and then `upgrade outdated` and it seems to be uninstalling and reinstalling all my ports with a message:

```
Warning: Deactivate forced.  Proceeding despite dependencies.
```

on each one. Luckily i made a copy of the *etc* and *apache2/conf* dirs, so should be able to get my config back when it eventually finishes... after 30 minutes or so it threw an error

```
Unable to open port: extra characters after close-quote
```

So i did `self update` again and `upgrade outdated` seems to run again...

So looks like it can be done (LAMP all working anyway) - it might have been quicker to start again from scratch, but make sure you have at least a couple of hours spare for this (and be connected to mains power ;)

Apologies if too much info, but hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Macports and the location of the Tcl framework and it's path once Xcode has been installed. I suggest installing a fresh version of Macports for Mavericks here : http://www.macports.org/install.php.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Mountain Lion and it was actually to do with MacPorts looking at an old XCode path (I had several versions including betas installed). I ran with the -d option and checked the config.log file at /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/base and it reported some errors:-

```
--- snip ---
...
configure:3331: checking for C compiler version
configure:3340: gcc --version >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
configure:3351: $? = 0
configure:3340: gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
...
--- snip ---
```

So I gave it the correct path using:-

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and that fixed it.

I got my clues from [this useful page](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist).