# port upgrade outdated fails in Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, port, osx-yosemite

I am trying to upgrade my MacPorts. I ran `sudo port -d selfupdate` successfully after updating my xcode command line, but the problem is persisting. How can I successfully upgrade my outdated installations? I am running Mac Yosemite.

```
$ sudo port upgrade outdated
--->  Fetching distfiles for python25
Error: python25 is not supported on Yosemite or later.
Error: org.macports.fetch for port python25 returned: unsupported platform
Please see the log file for port python25 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python25/python25/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

logfile:

```
$ cat /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python25/python25/main.log
version:1
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (python25)
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 502
:debug:fetch fetch phase started at Fri Jan  9 22:13:21 PST 2015
:notice:fetch --->  Fetching distfiles for python25
:debug:fetch Executing proc-pre-org.macports.fetch-fetch-0
:error:fetch python25 is not supported on Yosemite or later.
:error:fetch org.macports.fetch for port python25 returned: unsupported platform
:debug:fetch Error code: NONE
:debug:fetch Backtrace: unsupported platform
    while executing
"proc-pre-org.macports.fetch-fetch-0 org.macports.fetch"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $pre $targetname"
:info:fetch Warning: targets not executed for python25: org.macports.destroot org.macports.fetch org.macports.checksum org.macports.extract org.macports.patch org.macports.configure org.macports.build
:notice:fetch Please see the log file for port python25 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python25/python25/main.log
```

Comment: Did this start right after updating to Yosemite?

Comment: @myurtoglu After running some `port clean` commands, I am now getting a Yosemite specific error message. I have updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Bad news: After the Yosemite update, you should remove your old macports installation and reinstall everything.
Good news: This procedure is explained quite well and made easy with a tcl script [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration#Migrationprocedure). [Here is a similar question from last year.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622337/cant-update-macports-with-mac-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: Is this really a programming question?